# How do I rotate my viewport around the position of my cursor?

Tags: 3d-view

I have googled a lot and didn't find the answer.

I think in older Blender versions, if you for example middle mouse click on a model and drag, it rotates around the point you hovered your mouse cursor over, for example the surface of the model.

But since I updated to Blender 2.8 it always rotates around a fixed point somewhere in the distance, so I have to use the walk navigation to rotate around the model. For example I wanna rotate around the model but it rotates around a point far behind the model

Comment: *Tool Shelf Panel > View Tab > View Lock > Lock to 3D Cursor*. Check it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit -> Preferences

I think you need this to be checked.

[image: Orbit Around Selection]

This also could be interesting for zooming to/from mouse position

[image: Zoom to mouse position]

I found a nice [tutorial](https://artisticrender.com/how-to-move-the-camera-in-blender/) on that subject.

Comment: Hello :). Any idea on how blender sets the rotation center, when this option is disabled?

Comment: @JachymMichal Magical invisible point in space. Just try zooming in all the way until you can't anymore. Then you are there.

Comment: Thank you! That's already helpful. With your help I actually achieved my desired result by checking "Auto Depth" instead. :) So it rotates around where my cursor is

Comment: I don't want to orbit around selected, I just want to orbit around where my mouse cursor (not 3D cursor) is. Orbit Around Selection can do that if you don't select anything, but if you do select a loop, while zoomed in, it gets really hard to navigate because the imaginary orbit point becomes the median point of the loop you've selected. Is there any way?

Comment: @melly_berk The mouse moves on 2D plane, and rotation point needs 3D coordinates. It's not possible to rotate around your mouse because the depth is missing, and guessing it is a very hard task. I suggest using the "." (period) on numpad to automatically center and zoom to see entire selection.

Comment: It's, in fact, possible to orbit around your mouse cursor. Just open blender while Orbit Around Selection is enabled, add two meshes to different locations. Select each and try to navigate, you'll see you're navigating around their origin point. This time just hover your mouse on them and navigate without selecting those objects. You'll see navigation orbit points will be around those object's origins. I don't know maybe I'm wrong. I just feel like that :D @FilipFranik

Comment: @melly_berk Try "Auto Depth" without "Orbit Around Selection" seems like Blender actually can guess the depth. (Unfortunately IMHO it doesn't do the best job guessing it)

Comment: @FilipFranik Checking "Auto depth" or in the current version "Depth" next to the "Auto" keyword actually orbits around where you put your cursor on a 3D model and IMO it works just as good as in the old blender versions

Answer (score 1):

Default shortcut to pick the orbit point on your mesh: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> click